# Chrome renders white text too boldly

Tags: css, google-chrome, text-rendering

So, I'm working on a web design, coded in HTML/CSS and I want to ask if there's any workaround with CSS to make Chrome not to render white text too boldly.
Basically, the way Chrome renders text looks ugly, and I want it to look like, or almost like Firefox or Safari, which looks thinner and better. Here's an image of more or less what I want to achieve:
[image]

EDIT:

Code:

```
<head>

    <meta charset='UTF-8'/>

    <title></title>

    <style>

        body {
            background-image: url("image.jpg");
            background-size: 100%;

            font: 13px Verdana; color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        .content {
            width: 1024px
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 8px 16px;
        }

        .scape {
            width: 544px;

            margin: 256px auto;
            padding: 8px 16px;

            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class='content'>

        <div class='scape'>

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam convallis tellus a tortor iaculis, non sodales risus porttitor. Maecenas vel mauris nec ligula ultricies dictum. Ut ornare vel risus et malesuada. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque consectetur, dui in tristique fermentum, odio augue tempus nulla, ut vestibulum magna turpis vitae dolor. Integer quis nisi nisi. Praesent sit amet vestibulum ipsum. Quisque in pharetra massa, ac blandit augue. Sed vitae leo mattis, luctus dolor vel, ullamcorper ante.

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

I want Chrome to render the font better, thinner like in the other two browsers. I tried adding things like "-webkit-font-smoothing: none;", "text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;", "font-weight: normal;" and "-webkit-text-stroke: -1px;" but nothing changed.

Comment: Please include code that repros this issue, more details, and tell us what you've tried/researched so far. (You can edit your question to add details.)

Comment: This is annoying, but there are so many things that affect font-rendering in a browser (webfont-usage, OS, browser, browser version, system font settings) that it's nearly immpossible to get exactly the same result in all browsers in all OS. And you don't need that! Your text looks good and is readable.

Comment: Hmm, you're right @Panique, but I still find it kinda annoying, Chrome has a lot of bugs and stuff that doesn't work well, I guess I'll switch to Firefox as my main browser for now, at least until they fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Set a specific `font-weight` for Chrome.

Use the javascript

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Chrome/") != -1) {
// font weight css for body or div here
}
```

Try a font weight sligtly less than normal ie 300 or 200 and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

add css for `.scape`:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;font-weight:100;
```

this should do the job. hope that helps.

UPDATE:

if you want it to apple for **chrome only**, use some jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) {
        $('.scape').css('-webkit-font-smoothing', 'antialiased');
    }
});
```

and make sure that `font-weight:100` is declared for `.scape` css rule in the css file.

hope that helps.

Comment: The `font-weight` would also be applied to Firefox in this example. Note that Verdana does not come in lighter weights than 400 (Regular).